# Delete lines with a word using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I tried using `sed '/\bpassword\b/d'` and `sed "/\<password\>/d"` to find only lines that contain "password" and delete them but it doesn't work, the command also finds words like "password!" or "password@".

Let's say I have these words:

```
password
password1
password2
password!
password@
password%
password*
```

I only have to delete the line with "password" and not the others. Currently those two commands delete the "password@" , "password%" , "password!" and "password*" too.

Comment: ... what *shouldn't* come after `password`, then? Add example input and expected output, please.

Comment: @muru Let's say I have these words "password" , "password1" , "password2" , "password!" , "password@" , "password%" , "password*" . I only have to delete the line with "password" and not the others,currently those two commands delete the "password@" , "password%" , "password!" and "password*" too .

Comment: Add example input and output to the question by editing it.

Comment: @muru done,the topic is edited

Comment: Doesn't `sed 's/password//g'` do the job?

Comment: @George that command deleted ALL the words that included "password" including "password1" , "password2" etc

Comment: You are telling about _lines_ or _words_? Because even if your line contain **password** your commands deleting whole line!

Comment: `grep -vx password`

Answer (score 5):

If they appear on one line per word, use the ^ and $ to match start of line and end of line.
Consider the following sample file `foo`:

```
$ cat foo
password
password!1
password2
2password
```

Using sed matching beginning and end of line replaces only the line consisting of solely `password`

```
$ sed '/^password$/d' foo
password!1
password2
2password
```

Answer (score 2):

It's currently unclear whether the lines you want to delete may contain anything but the string `password`. I'm to assume that they do because [vidarlo’s answer](/a/974661/175814) already covers the opposite.

The (extended) regular expression

```
(^|\s)password(\s|$)
```

matches all strings that start at the start-of-line or with whites-space, followed by the infix `password`, followed by either white-space or end-of-line.

The respective `sed` command is:

```
sed -re '/(^|\s)password(\s|$)/d'
```

Alternatively you can use `grep` in inverse mode:

```
grep -vEe '(^|\s)password(\s|$)'
```